# Adding two DateTime objects together

Tags: c#, datetime, addition

Is there any better way to add one DateTime object to another one, than this:

```
DateTime first = new DateTime(2000, 1, 1);
DateTime second = new DateTime(11, 2, 5, 10, 10, 11);

DateTime result = first.AddYears(second.Year);
DateTime result = first.AddMonths(second.Month);
...
```

and so on...

In this example I'd like to get `DateTime(2011, 3, 6, 10, 10, 11)`

**EDIT**

After a intensive brainstorm it seems to there's no different way, but to facilitate it can be boxed inside additional class and operator+ just like in JonSkeet's answer

Comment: @TimSchmelter: Creating `Add`/`+` function/operator for DateTime has no sense in the way you suggest, because the `DateTime` type does not have a neutral value ("zero"). You cannot construct a `second` instance that will provide a `Month=0`, so for this way of "adding" a "1 year" will either add 1 year 1 month, or you will need to convert the `second` manually to "december" (12month) to get a real 1year offset. It gets even more complicated after you notice that there's the same problem with Days, which are not always convertible to simple "31". This is precisely why there's a `TimeSpan` type

Answer (score 36, accepted):

It doesn't make sense to add two `DateTime` values together. If you want to represent "11 years, 2 months, 5 days, 10 hours, 10 minutes and 11 seconds" then you should represent that. That's *not* the same as 0011-02-05T10:10:11. In particular, you'd never be able to add "2 months and 30 days" for example. Likewise you'd never be able to add just a single year, because you can't have 0 for month and day values within a date.

Now there's no BCL type to represent the idea of "11 years [...]" but you could create your own one reasonably easily. As an alternative, you could use my [Noda Time](http://nodatime.org) project which has `Period` for precisely this purpose:

```
var localDateTime = new LocalDate(2000, 1, 10).AtMidnight();
var period = new PeriodBuilder {
    Years = 11, Months = 2, Days = 5,
    Hours = 10, Minutes = 10, Seconds = 11
}.Build();
var result = localDateTime + period;
```

Contrary to some other answers provided here, you *cannot* use `TimeSpan` for this purpose. `TimeSpan` doesn't have any concept of months and years, because they vary in length, whereas a `TimeSpan` represents a fixed number of ticks. (If your largest unit is days, then you're fine to use `TimeSpan`, but given your example, I assume you need months and years.)

If you don't want to use Noda Time, I'd recommend you fake up a `Period`-like class yourself. It's easy enough to do - for example:

```
// Untested and quickly hacked up. Lots more API you'd probably
// want, string conversions, properties etc.
public sealed class Period
{
    private readonly int years, months, days, hours, minutes, seconds;

    public Period(int years, int months, int days,
                  int hours, int minutes, int seconds)
    {
        this.years = years;
        this.months = months;
        this.days = days;
        this.hours = hours;
        this.minutes = minutes;
        this.seconds = seconds;
    }

    public static DateTime operator+(DateTime lhs, Period rhs)
    {
        // Note: order of operations is important here.
        // Consider January 1st + (1 month and 30 days)...
        // what do you want the result to be?
        return lhs.AddYears(rhs.years)
                  .AddMonths(rhs.months)
                  .AddDays(rhs.days)
                  .AddHours(rhs.hours)
                  .AddMinutes(rhs.minutes)
                  .AddSeconds(rhs.seconds);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
DateTime first = new DateTime(2000, 1, 1);
Period second = new Period(11, 2, 5, 10, 10, 11);
DateTime result = first + second;
```

You need to be aware of how `DateTime.Add` will handle impossible situations - for example adding a month to January 31st will give you February 28th/29th depending on whether or not it's a leap year.

The simple approach I've listed here, going through intermediate values, has its downsides, because that truncation can happen twice (adding years and then adding months) when it needn't - for example, "February 29th + 1 year + 1 month" might logically be "March 29th" but it will actually end up as "March 28th" as the truncation to February 28th will happen before the month is added.

Trying to work out a "right" way of doing calendrical arithmetic is [fiendishly difficult](http://blog.nodatime.org/2010/11/joys-of-datetime-arithmetic.html), particularly as in some cases people may disagree about what the "right" answer is. In the above code I've opted for simplicity and predictability - depending on your real requirements, you may need something more complex.

Comment: Yes, so the `second` variable should be of `TimeSpan` type - then it could be easy to add it to `DateTime`.

Comment: @pwas: No, because you can't represent "11 years and 2 months" as a TimeSpan.

Comment: It's a bit of a pain to use `TimeSpan` since the ctor only supports up to days. Not impossible, but definitely annoying after a while.

Comment: @code4life: No, it *is* impossible. What would a `TimeSpan` representing "1 month" look like? How many ticks are in it?

Comment: @Jon: You'd have to figure out whether it's a 30-day month, a 31-day month, or a February, or a February in a leap year. It's possible, but a much wiser approach would be to use a library that has been tested and found worthy.

Comment: Argh - another thought just came to mind. If you're in the financial sector, a month could just mean 30 days (using a 360 day count days rule). In which case it's another wrinkle to deal with...

Comment: @code4life: No, it's *not* possible without the extra context. Note how `second` is being constructed *without* reference to `first`. The idea is to combine two independent values - and there's no way of making a `TimeSpan` independently represent "1 month".

Comment: @Jon: hmm... my understanding of this ctor: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6c7z43tw(v=vs.110).aspx was that it results in a `TimeSpan` corresponding to *x* number of days, hours, minutes, etc. So as long as you can answer the question of "how many days is it?", wouldn't you be able to get the `TimeSpan` that you desire?

Comment: @code4life: Yes, but the OP clearly wants to be able to represent "11 years and 2 months" which *can't* be expressed in a number of days, independently of some base date. If your largest unit is days, then sure, TimeSpan is fine.

Comment: @quetzalcoatl: It would do whatever `DateTime.Add*` does, which is to truncate to the end of the month where necessary. That's pretty common practice in date/time APIs. I'll add a note, but I wouldn't call it "just evil" - adding a period to a date is a *very* common requirement which we deal with every day in the real world.

Comment: @quetzalcoatl: It breaks "maths over natural numbers" yes, but that's not the same as being evil, IMO. I've added some notes at the end, but just because it's a sometimes-counterintuitive domain doesn't make the real world use of it any less important.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, do you take leap seconds in consideration in Noda Time?

Comment: @LucaCremonesi: Nope, we explicitly don't try to. Accounting for leap seconds is something very little software needs to do, and it would be hugely burdensome for most to take account of it.

Comment: It does indeed make sense to add two or more dates. In the context of .net it's different cause they choose to work with a dateTime object as a starting point and then add time differentials, but adding two dates together makes complete sense.

Comment: @MeTitus: I really don't think it does. Leaving programming out of it and just thinking conceptually, what would the result of adding "June 19th 1976" and "November 2nd 2020" be? How is the result *meaningful* in any sense?

Comment: @JonSkeet it all depends on the context. For me adding those two dates together means adding the diff between 1976 and 2020 and add it to the later, but I understand your point now - as soon as I had need for write "for me" it all became clear.

Comment: @MeTitus: I would suggest that's a *really* unusual use of the word "add", which is *completely* different to the normal arithmetic approach. 15+20=25 according to that... I would certainly not want that to be assumed as a "standard" interpretation of adding dates together. What you've described is absolutely achievable using multiple operations (at least in a good date/time library). I'm glad you understand my point though :)

Answer (score 7):

```
DateTime first = new DateTime(2000, 1, 1);
DateTime second = new DateTime(11, 2, 5, 10, 10, 11);

DateTime result = new DateTime(first.Ticks + second.Ticks);
```

Comment: After reading other solutions, your...
The simplest solution, the best

Answer (score 2):

You have a `DateTime` which represents a point in time.  And you want to add a number of years/months/days/hours/minutes/seconds to it.

A change in `DataTime` is not a point, it is a vector (a difference between points).  It is really easy to mistake one for the other, as they often have similar structure.  However, that kind of type error leads to lots of pain.

Avoiding it doesn't fix your pain, but it makes it manageable.

Adding two `DateTime` together is adding two points together.  Sort of like adding the location of Los Angeles to New York.

Now, adding the "vector" of LA to NY to London makes sense -- because the travel vector is a vector, not a point.  And point+vector is just a point.

So this means you need to create a time vector type.  A simple time span is an option, but probably not appropriate: because you care about months, years and days, not nanoseconds or absolute time durations.

I'll dub the name of the vector a `CalendarVector`, as it represents movement on a Calendar, not in time itself.

An easy first pass is to create a tuple of each sub type of time -- years, months, days, etc -- then add them in some arbitrary order to your original `DateTime` with an overloaded `operator+`.

You should support:

```
DateTime = DateTime + CalendarVector
CalendarVector = CalendarVector + CalendarVector
CalendarVector = CalendarVector - CalendarVector
CalendarVector = int * CalendarVector
CalendarVector = - CalendarVector
DateTime = DateTime - CalendarVector
CalendarVector = DateTime - DateTime
```

ideally.  The `CalendarVector + DateTime` overload is optional, but probably not needed.

However, this only gets you half way.

The big remaining problem is that CalendarVector addition **does not commute**.  Adding 1 month to a DateTime, then adding 1 day, is different than adding 1 day then adding 1 month.

And this is fundamental.

There is the problem of "what does it mean to be 1 month after January 31st", which can be answered, but any reasonable answer to that question doesn't solve the commuting problem.

Your planned constructor -- where you feed it the number of years, months, days, hours, minutes seconds -- is thus ambiguous in what it means.

So a robust solution should not have that constructor.

A solution is to create `Years`, `Months`, `Days`, `Hours`, `Minutes` and `Seconds` types that you explicitly add together.  The order they are added together is the order they are applied to the `DateTime` you add it to.  Commuting and "simplification" is avoided until the final application on a `DateTime` -- so `+1 year, +2 days, -1 month, -1 year, -2 days, +1 month` is *not* the zero transformation.

There is a related problem with `DateTime-DateTime` -- it should return a `CalendarVector` `v` such that `lhs = rhs + v`, but there are multiple such vectors.  The same problem can occur with spherical coordinates -- do you mean the short way around the Earth, or the long way?  It doesn't matter in some contexts -- but then you halve the result to find the mid-way point.  Plus, you get discontinuities as you approach "far side of the world".

So my advice would be to maintain a list of transformations on a `DateTime` object.  `1 year` is a transformation that consists of adding 1 to the year field, and then repairing the other fields so they are consistent.  These transformations support negation.  Addition is applying them one at a time, from left to right.  Negation may also reverse the order of application, and adjacent transformations "of the same kind" may combine (so +1 month -1 month becomes the identity transformation, instead of a clamping operation based off next months' end of month), or not (so `x = x+1 month`,then `x = x-1 month` on the next line is the same as `x = x + 1 month - 1 month`).

Yet another approach is to insist that the user provide a policy for what to do in these exceptional circumstances (which happen ... all the time), because this problem is thorny enough that a library that "solves" the problem can at best highlight the problems and force the client programmer to think about them and make decisions.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest is:

```
firstDateTime.AddTicks(secondDateTime.Ticks);
```