# Combining two Datetime values

Tags: c#

I'm pretty new to coding so sorry if my question has an obvious answer but I didn't find anything like that via the search.

I'm currently trying to make a time tracker database by using Windows Forms in C#.

My oroblem is the GUI has two `DateTimePicker`: one displays the hours (`dateTimePicker1`) which you can choose, and the other one displays the minutes (`dateTimePicker2`) you can choose.

Both of them are starting with the current time when the form is loading.

I'm now trying to combine those two so that I get a string which gives me both hours and minutes with the chosen time.

If someone could help me here I'd be really glad because I'm currently out of ideas....

Comment: Can you please show your work and tell what do you want as a result exactly?

Comment: duplicate from: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28067247/adding-two-datetime-objects-together

Comment: `string combined = dateTimePicker1.Value.Hour + ":" + dateTimePicker2.Value.Minute;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean like this?

```
// take hour from first datetimepicker
DateTime hour = dateTimePicker1.Value.Hour;
// take minute from second datetimepicker
DateTime minute = dateTimePicker2.Value.Minute;
// combine hour and minute into an object
DateTime hourAndMinute = hour + minute;
// convert the combined DateTime into string
hourAndMinute.ToString("hh:mm");
```

If you want to convert it to string with different format you can check it here http://www.dotnetperls.com/datetime-format

If you actually need to represent length of time you should use this one http://www.dotnetperls.com/timespan

Mark as an answer if it help you :)

Comment: That was what i was looking for. Thank you very much. Unfortunately my mark will only be shown if i earn enough Reputation so it might take a while. :)

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for this?

```
  // myDatePicker displays date 
  DateTime day = myDatePicker.Value.Date;
  // myTimePicker displays time
  var timeOffset = myTimePicker.Value.TimeOfDay;

  // combined value (day and time)
  DateTime result = day + timeOffset;
```

In case you have *three* DatePickers (date, hour and minutes):

```
  // myDatePicker displays date 
  DateTime day = myDatePicker.Value.Date;

  DateTime result = day
    .AddHours(myHourPicker.Value.Hour)
    .AddMinutes(myMinutePicker.Value.Minute);
```

To display in required format use formatting:

```
  // Hours and minutes
  String text = result.ToString("hh:mm");
```