# Sum two dates represented in a hh:mm:ss string format

Tags: c#, datetime

How can i put the 2 times together
And i want it to stay in the time format: hh:mm:ss

```
string time1 = "00:49:35";
string time2 = "00:31:34";

totaltime = time1 + time2;
```

This should be the result
01:21:09 (1 hour and 21 min and 09 sec)

Comment: What is your desired output?

Comment: How about doing a SO search first? Like e.g. "[Adding two DateTime objects together](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28067247/adding-two-datetime-objects-together)".

Comment: You're confusing data with representation. If your input is a string, you need to parse it to a sensible format (e.g. TimeSpan), then add those, and then print the timespan in the representation you want.

Comment: Checkout `DateTime` or `TimeSpan` there are thousands of such questions in SO

Comment: the 2 times together 01:21:09 (1 hour and 21 min and 09 sec)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about using the [TimeSpan](http://www.dotnetperls.com/timespan) class:

```
TimeSpan time1 = TimeSpan.Parse("00:49:35");
TimeSpan time2 = TimeSpan.Parse("00:31:34");

TimeSpan res = time1 + time2;

Console.WriteLine(res.ToString()); // 01:21:09, you may omit the ToString() call
```

---

If you don't want to `Parse` a string, you can construct a `TimeSpan` object:

```
TimeSpan time1 = new TimeSpan(00, 49 ,35);
TimeSpan time2 = new TimeSpan(00, 31 ,34);
TimeSpan res = time1 + time2;
Console.WriteLine(res); // 01:21:09
```

Answer (score 2):

This works for me:

```
(TimeSpan.Parse(time1) + TimeSpan.Parse(time2)).ToString()
```