# Program that calculates the addition of two times

Tags: c#

I need to write a program that calculates the addition of two times  in C# Example: time1 = 04:21:57 time2= 01:54:26 result = 06:16:23 . I'm still not very familiar with the language and I'm stuck like glue on this problem unable to find a solution. I would appreciate your help.

Comment: What are the type of time1 and time2?

Comment: If you google `C# time` I'm sure you'll find an answer pretty quickly.

Comment: If the purpose of this exercise is academic and to demonstrate things like conditional logic, then think about the exercise on a piece of paper first.  If you were a computer and you had these two inputs, what steps would you take to perform math on them?  Clearly you can't perform math on strings, so how would you turn them into meaningful numbers?  How would you then perform the calculations on those numbers?  How would you turn the result back into a time string?  The C# aspect of this is minimal, it's more about the logic.

Comment: You say you're not very familiar... I bet you didn't even try...

Comment: There's nothing said about what kind of data type they should be. But I guess they might be strings

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding two DateTime objects together](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28067247/adding-two-datetime-objects-together)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that what you call "time" is actually a *time span*, i.e. the difference between two absolute times.

If this is correct, .NET offers a good data type to deal with the problem: it's called [`TimeSpan`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan(v=vs.110).aspx). You can perform parsing and addition like this:

```
var a = TimeSpan.Parse("01:54:26");
var b = TimeSpan.Parse("06:16:23");
var c = a + b;
Console.WriteLine(c);
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/DzsRlC)

Note that the result may exceed 24 hours, in which case the sum would be expressed in days, hours, minutes, and seconds.

Answer (score 2):

Use [TimeSpan.Add Method (TimeSpan)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.add(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
TimeSpan time1 = TimeSpan.Parse("04:21:57");
TimeSpan time2 = TimeSpan.Parse("01:54:26");
TimeSpan result = time1.Add(time2);

Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

I will not give you the code, I'll just give you the idea:

Since you haven't provided enough information, I'm gonna assume that time1 and time2 are strings. You need to split them with a delimeter ":", then you first need to add seconds, and you'll calculate the module of the given sum by 60 (e.g. if you get 72, module is 12, so that'll be your result) and also division of that sum with 60 (you'll get either 1 or 0, do integer division).
You will add this to the sum of minutes as the transfer. Do the same thing for the sum of minutes, module by 60, that's the minutes, divide by 60 and add to the sum of hours.

Answer (score 0):

First, try to define a class "Time", who have some data int value (hours, minutes, sec) and define some basics private method (like increase hours when you have 60 min, and set to 0 min, same fonction for secunds)

Now, in your program main, define two time objectif, and with the method you've developed, you'll have an output.

Comment: Or just use `DateTime`. What happens in your class if you add `16:00:00` and `20:00:00` ?

Comment: No, because i think he is a student and this is not the purpose of his exercice